# How to pass an array instead of variable arguments in java?

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, arguments, parameter-passing

I want to pass an array instead of variable arguments to a java method. In similar questions people had answered that arrays are no different than ellipses so it must work. but it doesn't work for me.
Here is my code:

```
String[] parameters = text.split("[?]");
Object[] params = Arrays.asList(parameters).toArray(new Object[parameters.length]);
params[0] = myObject;
method.invoke(params)
```

Where *text* is something like: `myMethod?param1?param2 ...` But it can also be something like `myMethod` in case the method has no arguments.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

What should I do?

**Edited**:

I have checked and the value of the variable parameters is {myMethod, param1, param2}.

Comment: what makes you think there is a difference? have you tried split with just "?", what are the [ and ] doing there?

Comment: ***arrays are no different than ellipses*** wht do you mean with that?

Comment: by ellipse I mean variable number of arguments to be passed to a method.

Comment: So your method uses varargs? Like "public void myMethod(Object... arguments)?

Comment: no. not my method. the built in "invoke" method.

Comment: why you are putting ? in inside brackets???   it should be like split("?") i think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `?` while splitting, the below should split the String into array which you can pass to the method:

```
String s = "myMethod?param1?param2";
String[] tokens = s.split("\\?");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

Comment: `split("?")` should work as well. If only a single character is passed as argument, the character is used instead of the term being seen as regular expression.

Comment: @Lothar Just tried it, does't work. It throws `PatternSyntaxException` with message `Dangling meta character '?' near index 0`.

Comment: @Darshan I checked again. You're right, I misremembered the if-statement in `String#split` (was in the source to answer another question for myself a couple of weeks ago)

Comment: it has the same result for me anyway! actually when I put "?" it get's a red underline in intellij. [?] is regex.@DarshanMehta

Comment: Yes, it is regex. If you try the code snippet I provided above, it would work fine

Answer (score 0):

What is type of "myObject" and "method"?

invoke method should have the signature as follows 
returntype invoke(Object... o)//Object because params is Array Of Objects 
{
}

Comment: method is a setter which gets a String and returns it.

Comment: params[0] = myObject;
method.invoke(params) can you just ellaborate more